# Unable to take input from console in java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am new to Java and facing problem while taking input from the console.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;

class solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println(t);
        for (int n = 0; n < t; n++) {
            for (int i=0;i<4;i++){
                    int mzeroes  = sc.nextInt();
                    int nones = sc.nextInt();
                    int stringLength = sc.nextInt();
                    String string=sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.println(mzeroes);
                    System.out.println(nones);
                    System.out.println(stringLength);
                    System.out.println(string);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Input**:

```
2

2 2 8 11101000

3 4 16 0110111000011111
```

**Error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException: For input string: "0110111000011111"
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2123)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at solution.main(solution.java:13)
```

Comment: @Soumaya - EDIT: Added a missing brace and formatted the input.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same code but there were no errors and it executed successfully. I think you are making the mistake while giving the input. This is how the input has to be given :

[image]

As the first input is two so it will ask for two inputs in the loop and then when you pass the first input for the loop it will print out the there 3 ints one after other and the remaining string at the end. And the same goes for the second input of the loop.

**Note**: The `String string = sc.nextLine();` will give you the string so space before the last number will also be taken in the `string`.

Hope this helps.